# ImageMagick throwing conversion error for large image on AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, imagemagick

We have a program written in Java which I am deploying on AWS Lambda.

This program converts a given image into different thumbnails via Imagick which comes pre-installed on Lambda. We have setup the Lambda to use the maximum 1536 MB memory while in application have limited the convert command with:

```
imConvertPath = imPath + "convert  -limit memory 1GB -limit map 1350MB";
```

With this setting, the code is working fine for smaller images with a few MBs but when I try with a high res image of ~40MB it fails with this error:

> org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 135

What does this error mean? Does the program go into some sig fault issue or what?

Also when I run this program with via my stub code for testing it is able to convert it with out any issue.

Comment: Maybe check the settings for how much memory will be used before the operations start paging to disk, which is one of the policies that can be set in ImageMagick. Also, contact Amazon support.

Comment: It is failing the conversion as Imagick requires ~4 GB of memory or disk space while on AWS Lambda we are limited in resources e.g. Max memory is 1536MB, Disk space 500MB etc. 

These limits can increased by asking AWS Support but still we will be hitting the limit in one way or another way so reading further on this to come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you are doing the shrinking, but if you are resizing JPEG images, you must use libjpeg shrink-on-load for good performance.

For example, on this machine (2012 imac) with a 10,000 x 10,000 pixel RGB jpeg image and IM 7.0.5-5 I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l convert wtc.jpg -resize 500x500 x.jpg
        6.87 real         6.06 user         0.51 sys
1269547008  maximum resident set size
```

So about 7s and 1.2GB of memory. If I use shrink-on-load, where you hint to the jpeg loader what pixel dimensions you need, I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l convert -define jpeg:size=1000x1000 wtc.jpg -resize 500x500 x.jpg
        0.32 real         0.27 user         0.02 sys
  34181120  maximum resident set size
```

Down to 0.3s and 34MB of memory.

This will only work for JPEG files, but it does help dramatically. You need to hint a size twice your final output or you'll see aliasing.

To improve performance with other file types you'd need to look at other image resize programs. I help maintain [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/), a streaming image processing library. It can decode, process and recode as a continuous stream of pixels, so it does not need to keep entire images in memory.

With a 30,000 x 30,000 JPEG and **convert**, I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l convert -define jpeg:size=1000x1000 big.jpg -resize 500x500 x.jpg
        3.08 real         2.92 user         0.14 sys
 300138496  maximum resident set size
```

3.1s and 300MB of memory, but with **vipsthumbnail** I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l vipsthumbnail big.jpg --size 500x500 -o x.jpg
        2.38 real         2.31 user         0.06 sys
  28385280  maximum resident set size
```

2.4s and 28MB of memory.

The differences become much larger with formats like TIFF where there is no shrink-on-load system. With a 10,000 x 10,000 RGB TIFF I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l convert wtc.tif -resize 500x500 x.jpg
        5.81 real         4.97 user         0.60 sys
1503449088  maximum resident set size
```

5.8s and 1.5GB of memory, versus:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l vipsthumbnail wtc.tif --size 500x500 -o x.jpg
        1.43 real         0.47 user         0.08 sys
  42360832  maximum resident set size
```

1.4s and 42MB of memory.

There's a very nice node.js image resize package called [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) based on libvips which should deploy on lambda, or if you want to use the command-line vipsthumbnail program from Java, there are various builders, for example:

https://github.com/stechstudio/libvips-lambda

There's a blog post introducing vipsthumbnail here:

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html

Comment: sharp won't run out of the box in lambda and the instructions on dozens of threads in the sharp repository are varied and convoluted. I tried at least half-a-dozen suggested 'fixes' to get it to work and any time any one of them shows any level of success, I get some other error in it's place